# How show current screen name in app.js using useRoute?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, navigation, react-navigation

I am trying get current screen name in app.js, I am using useRoute inside Notification handler but is not showing.

```
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({  
 handleNotification: (n) => {    
  const { keeperId, type } = n?.request?.content?.data ?? {};     
  const route = useRoute();      
  console.log('route name');      
  console.log(route.name)      
  const showNotification = keeperId === store.getState().chat.chat.keeperUserId;        
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    resolve({
      shouldShowAlert: showNotification,
      shouldPlaySound: false,
      shouldSetBadge: false,
    }),
  );
 },
});
```

Comment: what versions are you using? is it outputting an empty string?

Comment: I am using 5.9.4 and Notifications.setNotificationHandler stop working when i am using useRoute.

Comment: what is Notifications? is this _React_? or javascript? A global javascript can't use react hooks! hooks can be only used with _React_ function component.

Comment: I am using expo notifications

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this using

```
export const navigationRef = React.createRef();


navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name
```